Meta -- The page admin who installs the app has ceased being an admin
I have this problem with my Meta/Facebook Webhook, It does not allow sending data to my CRM, when I test it the webhook returned me this error "The page admin who installs the app has ceased being an admin".
I don't understand if I have to delete and create a new app (something that I don't want to do) or maybe change this app admin somewhere.
PD: I have role admin, but I didn't create the app, the one how did it is no longer working with us.
PD2: The function that retrieve the data is located in Google Cloud Functions (I don't think this matters for the webhook error)

Message doesn't sound as if it was about your app admin. The page admin that originally installed your app on the page, isn't an admin of the page any more by now - so a current page admin will have to re-install it.

@C3roe, Do You have any link about how to re-install it?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-pages#install-app
